# Joining a Multi array and a single array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, merge

This may be easy, but it has me stuck today... (I have this code working by hitting the DB multiple times, trying to write it with just one pull from the DB.)

I have 2 arrays.  1st array is a log of transactions.  Bottom line, I want to show a count, for each 'modelid' and eliminate duplicate lines.  So I took array1, counted modelid and created array2.  I need to match the counts from array2 into array1.  I may be able to do this another way than I have started, I am down a rabbit hole now...

```
Array1
(
 [0] => Array
 ( 
 [modelid] => value1
 [model_display => value2
 [year] => value3
 )
[1] => Array
 (
 [modelid] => value1
 [model_display => value2
 [year] => value3
 )
)
```

// about 50 rows or so.

Now, array2

```
 (
  [modelid] => count1 (this is a count of this modelid found in array 1)
  [modelid2] => count2
  [modelid3] => count3
 )
```

I created array2 with this code using array1 as the source:

```
        $count = array();           
        foreach ($res as $r)
        {
        @$count[$r['modelid']]++;
        }
```

I want to merge these two arrays.  Removing dups from array1 and add counts to array2, OR take array2 and add model_display and year to array2.

So the end result would be (if adding array2 counts into array1 format:

```
newarray1
(
[0] => Array
 (
 [modelid] => value1
 [model_display => value2
 [year] => value3
 [count] => count1 (matching the modelid from both arrays)
 )
[1] => Array
 (
 [modelid] => value1
 [model_display => value2
 [year] => value3
 [count] => count2
 )
)
```

Last would be to sort the array, by count, DESC.

Comment: There are 3 php array functions you can use to achieve your goal: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php](array_column), [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php](array_count_values) and [http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php](usort). Check them out and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I am on php 5.3, so a few restrictions on the suggested items. (Should of added that info, sorry.)

Comment: Well, I got it working...  Array 1 is the same, count like I show above, but then I simply echo out the results by matching the modelid. Sloppy, but works with one DB pull and much faster on load.

   Sort array by array_multisort() then a foreach on array2 while bringing in data from array1.

Comment: @BigB You claim your question is resolved, but there is no posted answer.  Please either post a meaningful answer and mark it as accepted; or if a meaningful answer that will be helpful to future readers cannot be generated, please delete this question so that it is removed from the long list of unanswered SO questions.